django-dbbackup mediarestore causes ValueError: Cannot determine path without bucket name
I'm trying to restore my media files to my Google Cloud Storage bucket. When I run python3 manage.py mediarestore -I [FILEPATH], I get the error ValueError: Cannot determine path without bucket name.
I have tried specifying my Google Cloud storage information in settings.py with:
DBBACKUP_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.gcloud.GoogleCloudStorage'
DBBACKUP_STORAGE_OPTIONS = {
        "bucket_name": "my-bucket-name",
        "project_id": "my-project-id",
        "blob_chunk_size": 1024 * 1024
}


but I still get the error.
Is there some other setting I need to configure?
